# bootstrap carousel not working, but turning into background images

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Im pretty much a newbie to coding and ive been trying to do a slider on bootstrap for a whle but it's not really working as it becomes something like a background

heres my HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class= "container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href"#">
                    <img src="img/logowine.png" alt="winelogo">
                </a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynavbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="mynavbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#about">About </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#product">Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div clas="item active">
                <img src="img/carousel1.jpg" alt="portdicksonrj" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div clas="item">
                <img src="img/carousel2.jpg" alt="portdicksonrjice" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div clas="item">
                <img src="img/carousel3.jpg" alt="portdicksonrjlemon" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#carousel").carousel();
    </script>




</body>
```

it comes out like
 [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmasR.jpg)
and
 [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Inuq.png)

Comment: do you have the bootsrap css linked on it?

Comment: See:

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss **spelling** of your **class word** just change your **HTML** `clas` to `class` Solve your problem .

**NB:** Also Please ensure it you was add **Bootstrap CSS**

**NB:** I Edit Your Question so now it's working well.

Look at my Bootstrap Carousel.

```css
 .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
}

.item img {
  height: 400px !important
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/Goole.jpg" alt="Chania 1" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://peterwardhomes.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/goole-area-shot_005.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/Travel/Destinations/Europe/France/Nice/Nice-nightlife-coastline-xlarge.jpg" alt="Flower 1" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01858/nice3_1858695b.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://eastriding.limehouse.co.uk/events/21318/images/highresRGB/2376387_0_1.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>   
    <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/carousel1.jpg" alt="First Slide">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/carousel1.jpg" alt="Second Slide">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/carousel1.jpg" alt="Third Slide">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```